Can I disable the JVMs monitoring stats from New Relic?
I already have another source to monitor the JVM specific stats and I would like to find a way to stop sending those stats to New Relic.
I have the new relic java agent installed (com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-agent:8.8.0) and I have previously managed to play around with settings by either using the newrelic.yml file or directly changing the environment variables, so I know they work.
Eg: I've disabled distributed tracing using the environment variables like so: NEW_RELIC_DISTRIBUTED_TRACING_ENABLED=false or enabled thread profiler using the config yml file like so:
   thread_profiler:
    enabled: true

and both worked fine.
But I couldn't find a way to stop getting JVM stats.
This is what I've tried so far:
Env variables:
NEW_RELIC_JFR_ENABLED: false
NEW_RELIC_DISABLE_JVM_METRICS: true
NEW_RELIC_DISABLE_JMX: true
NEW_RELIC_JMX_DISABLED: true
NEW_RELIC_SEND_JVM_PROPS: false
NEW_RELIC_ENABLED: false
NEW_RELIC_JMX_ENABLED: false
NEW_RELIC_SEND_ENVIRONMENT_INFO: false

also newrelic.yml changes:
 jmx:
   enabled: false

disable_jmx: true
send_jvm_props: false
send_environment_info: false

Of course, after the changes have been applied the services have been restarted, but with no luck.
I would really appreciate your help! Thank you
